# what does this really mean

Tags: statistics

what exactly does this expression mean, i keep seeing it in statistics but i never really understood what its supposed to be, is it another way of writing the variance

$$\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$$

btw the variance expression i am familiar with is $Var(X)= E(X^2)- [E(X)]^2$, would the expression above be a different way of writing this expression ^, if not what does it mean then, or at least please explain what the variables in the expression are supposed to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version:

$$E(X^2)- [E(X)]^2$$

is the vector form of the version:

$$\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2$$

The second operates at the level of elements $i$ of the first version's vectors.

Comment: see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help

$$Var(X) = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2 = E[(X-\mu)^2].$$